How to stretch the DropdownMenu width to the full width of the screen?
With Material 3, I have a DropdownMenu widget, which I constructed as:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

enum ListTime {
  first('8:00-9:35', '8:00', '9:35'),
  second('9:45-11:20', '9:45', '11:20'),
  third('11:35-13:10', '11:35', '13:10'),
  fourth('13:40-15:15', '13:40', '15:15'),
  fifth('15:25-17:00', '15:25', '17:00'),
  sixth('17:10-18:45', '17:10', '18:45'),
  seventh('18:55-20:30', '18:55', '20:30');

  const ListTime(this.label, this.start, this.end);
  final String label;
  final String start;
  final String end;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 12.0,
          ),
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: DropdownMenu(
              width: double.infinity,
              menuStyle: MenuStyle(),
              leadingIcon: Icon(
                Icons.schedule_outlined,
                size: 20,
              ),
              dropdownMenuEntries: ListTime.values
                  .map<DropdownMenuEntry<ListTime>>((ListTime time) {
                return DropdownMenuEntry<ListTime>(
                  value: time,
                  label: time.label,
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


However, when I set the DropdownMenu's width as double.infinity, the drop-down menu itself exceeds the width of the DropdownMenu widget.
I also wrapped it in Expand and Sizedbox.expand, but it then displayed an error.
A complete code sample has been added. Copy and paste it into DartPad.  After that, you will see that the drop-down list is much wider than the input field.


use width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width

What is the parent widget structure of this, can you include simple dartPadt version

Please check on your side first if the parent widget (i.e., Container, etc.) doesn't cause the child widget (i.e., DropdownMenu) to have padding horizontally.

If not padding. Then it might be a fixed width or something that holds the DropdownMenu to occupy the available space on the screen.

Edited the question by adding a complete code sample

Here is your solution.
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum ListTime {
  first('8:00-9:35', '8:00', '9:35'),
  second('9:45-11:20', '9:45', '11:20'),
  third('11:35-13:10', '11:35', '13:10'),
  fourth('13:40-15:15', '13:40', '15:15'),
  fifth('15:25-17:00', '15:25', '17:00'),
  sixth('17:10-18:45', '17:10', '18:45'),
  seventh('18:55-20:30', '18:55', '20:30');

  const ListTime(this.label, this.start, this.end);
  final String label;
  final String start;
  final String end;
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('ListTime Dropdown Example'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: ListTimeDropdown(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListTimeDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListTimeDropdown({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListTimeDropdown> createState() => _ListTimeDropdownState();
}

class _ListTimeDropdownState extends State<ListTimeDropdown> {
  // The selected value (defaulting to the first item in the enum)
  ListTime _selectedTime = ListTime.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        const Text(
          'Select Time Slot:',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 16),
        Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: ButtonTheme(
            alignedDropdown: true,
            child: DropdownButton<ListTime>(
              value: _selectedTime,
              items: ListTime.values.map((ListTime time) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<ListTime>(
                  value: time,
                  child: Text(time.label),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (ListTime? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  if (newValue != null) {
                    _selectedTime = newValue;
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Text(
          'Selected: ${_selectedTime.label}',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


No. Your method with the addition of width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,  does not solve the problem. The drop-down window still exceeds the input field. However, I noticed that in the "main channel" version, the drop-down list starts to position relative to the left edge.

I have updated the code please check. You can use DropDownButton instead of DropdownMenu to achieve the following UI
